# how getters work in projection interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I know how to implement a projection. What I want to ask is how the getters, like `getTranSeq()`, work in the projection interface? Why is `String getTranSeq()` a valid assignment? Is this something implemented by Spring Data JPA or Java itself?

I have looked through [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.closed) and noticed it mentioned **projection proxy**.

> If you use a closed projection, Spring Data can optimize the query execution, because we know about all the attributes that are needed to back the projection proxy.

But I'm not sure if proxy is referring to the getters in projection interface. Is there any other documentations explain more on how proejction getters work? Or could someone explain it in detail? Thanks!

```java
// projection

public interface TranRecordView {
    
    String getTranSeq();
    LocalDateTime getTranDate();
    String getCustomerId();
    Long getTranAmount();
}
```

```java
// repository

public interface TranRecordRepository extends CrudRepository<TranRecord, String> {
    
    List<TranRecordView> findBycustomerId(String customerId);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Proxy is the keyword here. It's the same technique for properties of interface based projections as for repositories itself.
Spring Data creates a Java Proxy for those interfaces.

There is not much documentation about these internals for Spring Data, except the source code.
For proxies in general there is plenty of information out there.
For example: https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies

Comment: when referring to projection proxy, is it referring to the projection object that includes all getters?? or is `string getTranSeq()` such assignment also a proxy??

Comment: what i want to know is why `string getTranSeq()` is a valid assignment in java

Comment: The interface is implemented by the proxy. `String getTranSeq()` is part of the interface and therefore implemented by the proxy. It is not a valid assignment since it is no assignment at all.

Comment: so `String getTranSeq()` is just like a normal `String tranSeq` in the interface, but the proxy created by spring data knows how to handle the name `getTranSeq()`?

Comment: `String tranSeq` would declare a field which isn't possible in an interface. `String getTranSeq()` is just a normal getter method. And yes, the proxy knows to handle it.

Comment: thank you so much for answering! it now makes sense after realizing interface only contains methods. `String getTranSeq()` is just a getter method with `String` return type. I kept assuming it being a field declaration (embarrassing mistake!)